# How do you write 'нипочему'?

Tags: правописание

Is ***ни*** written separately or together with the main word? And is it ***ни*,** or is it ***не***?

Answer (score 6):

This depends on what word/sequence you really mean. Depending on the context there can be

```
ни почему 
нипочему 
ни по чему
не почему
непочему
не по чему
ну почему
ну по чему
но почему
но по чему
```

Examples:

```
- Он ни о чем меня не спрашивал - *ни почему*, ни зачем.

- Почему ты злишься на меня? 
- *Нипочему*, просто так.

- Я уже *ни по чему* не скучаю.

- По чему ты перешёл на этот берег?
- *Ни по чему* не перешёл, я переплыл.

- Спрашивать надо было *не почему*, а зачем.

- Я бы перешел на тот берег, да *непочему*.

- По чему она скучает?
- *Не по чему*, а по кому.
```

Comment: Sorry Anixx, I am really curious: I've never met the word **непочему**,only **незачем**, could you please add a quote?

Comment: Or maybe it means in your example that there is no bridge?

Comment: @Umari yes. It means there is no bridge.

Comment: OK, understood. However,this word is new to me, could you please share a link from a dictionary?

Comment: @Umari it has stress on the first е.

Comment: I know, I guessed it from the meaning, it is the same as незачем, не к кому, не за что etc.

Comment: @Umari http://www.radikal.ru/GALLERY/PageF4G.aspx?i=ff8ed1dc91ef46c0a36e1de3e029450d

Comment: The problem is that I really do feel it has to be written separately... But I don't want to argue before I find some actual proof from reference literature.

Comment: I have a strong belief that in - Я бы перешел на тот берег, да *непочему*. and - *Нипочему*, просто так. the word in question has to be written separately. Can you give the rule which explicitly says that these words should be written without spaces?

Comment: @Olga http://ozhegov.info/slovar/?ex=Y&q=%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%9C%D0%A3

Comment: @Olga: it's *не по чему* but *нипочему*, see Rosenthal, #72.2 and #71.7

Comment: Maybe @Anixx should change her example then.